# Prestashop fatal error on products list page

Tags: php, function, methods, prestashop

I suddenly had this issue on my Prestashop project. When I'm opening the products list page, I have a blank page with this message :

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Product::getProductsImgs()...product-list.tpl.php on line 76

The error line : `{$more_imgs = Product::getProductsImgs($product.id_product)}`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the following:

Advanced parameters > performance > debug mode > disable all overrides

check if it is set to no.

Answer (score 0):

Check The following points first..
1) Did you try to modify the controller?
2) Did you add any custom code to product-list.tpl? 
if yes post it and also a few lines above and below the line mentioned..
Call to undefined method means you don't have the file with the method referenced..